# Add value to every pixel in the image to adjust the colours. Python 3

Tags: python, image, pixel

I need to write a program which reads in a red, green and blue value and adds that value to every pixel in the image to adjust the colours.

Here's an example where I'm adding 40 to the green value of every pixel, but adding nothing to the red and blue channels:

```
File name: dragonfly.png
Red tint: 0
Green tint: 40
Blue tint: 0
```

My code is below and it runs. But when I submit it, it says that "submission created the output image output.png, but it did not match the expected output image."  I have attached two pictures - actual and expected.

Please see my code:

```
import Image
file = input("File name: ")
red_tint = int(input("Red tint: "))
green_tint = int(input("Green tint: "))
blue_tint = int(input("Blue tint: "))
img = Image.open(file)
r,g,b = img.getpixel( (0,0) )
for y in range(img.height):
    for x in range(img.width):
        current_color = (r,g,b)
        if current_color == r:
            R = r + red_tint
        if current_color == g:
            G = g + green_tint
        if current_color == b:
            B = b + blue_tint
        R, G, B = current_color
        new_color = (R, G, B)
        img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
img.save('output.png')
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?  Thank you

actual picture[image: actual picture]

expected outcome [image: expected outcome]

Comment: Does the file your program outputs look anything like the expected outcome? Also: what are R, G, and B supposed to be in your loop? You never actually get pixel (x, y) in your code. It looks like you just set them all to the same value.

Comment: R,G,B are supposed to be new values for red,green,blue

Comment: then they should be derived from the old values then. You should be getting the rgb values from pixel (x,y) in your loop.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez can you please explain more on how to do it? whatever I keep trying to do - doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a stretch here as I don't know what the code is actually producing but instead of `img.putpixel()` make a pixel map like `px = img.load()`, then use `px[x,y] = new_color`

EDIT :

My understanding is you just want to edit the image based on the users input. So why not just add the RGB value to each? I haven't test this code.

```
for y in range(img.height):
    for x in range(img.width):
        current_color = px[x,y]
        new_color = (current_color[0] + int(red_tint), current_color[1] + int(green_tint), current_color[2] + int(blue_tint))
        px[x,y] = new_color
```

Comment: Looks like I'm getting a solid color picture

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
Here is the most vectorized method that handles integers above 255 correctly

```
import Image
import numpy as np

r = int(input('Red: '))
g = int(input('Green: '))
b = int(input('Blue: '))

np_img = np.array(img, dtype = np.float32)

np_img[:,:,0] += r
np_img[:,:,1] += g
np_img[:,:,2] += b

np_img[np_img > 255] = 255
np_img = np_img.astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(np_img, 'RGB')
img.save('output.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as I was doing the same question and after analysing everyones answers I found a solution

```
    from PIL import Image
    file = input("File name: ")
    red_tint = int(input("Red tint: "))
    green_tint = int(input("Green tint: "))
    blue_tint = int(input("Blue tint: "))
    img = Image.open(file)
    red, green, blue = img.split()
    for y in range(img.height):
       for x in range(img.width):
       value = img.getpixel((x, y))
       new_color = (value[0] + int(red_tint), value[1] + int(green_tint), value[2] + int(blue_tint))
       img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
    img.save('output.png')
```

Hoped this helped

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks